# Get height of auto-layout cell with wrapped text in it

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath and would like to use my already laid out prototype cell with auto layout to find the height. I've tried all of the following and none of them give me the actual height of the cell. They seem to give me the height of the cell before the labels are word wrapped.

I know I can use NSString methods to find the height of each string and figure out the cell's height that way but if I go down that road, I'm basically duplicating auto-layout's functionality and will have to maintain the cell's layout in two places. I really would like to avoid that and I'm assuming I'm missing something really simple here.

My prototype cell's height is set to 67 in IB and the content view's height is set to 66 in IB.

[image]

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"in heightForRowAtIndexPath: %@", indexPath);

    if (!self.prototypeCell)
    {
        self.prototypeCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MessageCell"];
    }

    // set the text in the labels
    [self configureCell:self.prototypeCell forIndexPath:indexPath isForOffscreenUse:YES];

    [self.prototypeCell setNeedsLayout];
    [self.prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];

    // this gives 58 regardless of the length of the text in my labels
    CGSize contentViewSize = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    // this gives me 58.5 regardless of the length of text in my labels
    CGSize cellSize = [self.prototypeCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

    return cellSize.height;
}
```

Comment: You're so close to getting it right! It might help you to see a working example. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch08p424variableHeights/ch21p722variableHeights/RootViewController.m That is part of a downloadable project so you can actually see it operate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the label's preferred width:

```
// the label is inside the table view 8 points from each edge
messageCell.message.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = tableView.frame.size.width - 16;
```